# "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED.

I'm trying to make an update profile page for an Express app with Mongoose, and I got the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')". I am confused how to fix it. Here is my code, thanks

```
exports.editProfilePost = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const username = req.user.username;
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ username: username }, req.body, {
      new: true,
    });
    res.redirect('/profile');
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

(error shown)
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xss8j.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... idk why this works but I forgot to make the profile picture push to cloudinary. Somehow, not pushing to cloudinary made the req.body empty, resulting in the error.

Answer (score 0):

The req.user could be undefined.
To debug, add the checking:

```
let username = "";
if (typeof req.user !== "undefined") {
   username = req.user.username;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it isn't working unfortunatley

Comment: Print out the value of variable req and res. This to ensure both variable contain correct attribute and is a valid object. Can use console.log to print the text into console.

Comment: I just now did a console.log to the req object, and I found `body: {}` in it. So the req.body is empty. Have any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error in an `egg.js` based project and `mongoose`. Here it is my  stack trace:

```
2023-08-30 12:54:34,140 ERROR 1900 nodejs.TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')
    at Singleton.createOneClient [as create] (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg-mongoose\lib\mongoose.js:67:16)
    at Singleton.createInstance (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg\lib\core\singleton.js:88:17)    
    at Singleton.initSync (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg\lib\core\singleton.js:31:27)
    at Singleton.init (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg\lib\core\singleton.js:21:68)
    at Application.addSingleton (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg\lib\egg.js:474:35)
    at module.exports (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg-mongoose\lib\mongoose.js:34:7)
    at module.exports (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg-mongoose\app.js:4:57)
    at Hook.configDidLoad (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg-core\lib\lifecycle.js:99:9)
    at Lifecycle.triggerConfigDidLoad (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg-core\lib\lifecycle.js:154:14)
    at Lifecycle.triggerConfigWillLoad (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg-core\lib\lifecycle.js:148:10)
    at AppWorkerLoader.loadCustomApp (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg-core\lib\loader\mixin\custom.js:37:20)
    at AppWorkerLoader.load (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg\lib\loader\app_worker_loader.js:35:10)
    at new Application (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg\lib\application.js:66:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\myproj\node_modules\egg-cluster\lib\app_worker.js:23:9)       
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)

pid: 1900
hostname: mypc
```

The error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasOwnProperty')` is too generic. I had to try every option to find out the solution. In my case, the reason was `mongoose` configuration. See my initial config:

```
  config.mongoose = {
    client: {
      url: 'mongodb://',
      migrationUrl: 'mongodb://',
    },
  };
```

To fix the issue I just added the `options` as `options: { useCreateIndex: true },`. See the complete and working configuration as below:

```
  config.mongoose = {
    client: {
      url: 'mongodb://',
      migrationUrl: 'mongodb://',
      options: { useCreateIndex: true },
    },
  };
```